# Spring Config from XML to Java not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config

I cannot seem to get simple Spring application to work with JavaConfig.

```
public class WebApp extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(WebApp.class);

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[0];
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{ WebAppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{ "/" };
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        logger.debug("onStartup");
        super.onStartup(servletContext);//MUST HAVE
        servletContext.setInitParameter("defaultHtmlEscape", "true");
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @ComponentScan("com.doge.controller")
    public static class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    }
}
```

And controller:

```
package com.doge.controller;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String sayHello() {
        System.out.println("something");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

I always get 404 on "localhost:8080/Build" nor "localhost:8080".
Nothing is ever logged nor printed, just "INFO: Server startup in 538 ms".

Answer (score 0):

There are few options of initialize Spring web application. The easiest is like below:

```
public class SpringAnnotationWebInitializer extends AbstractContextLoaderInitializer {

  @Override
  protected WebApplicationContext createRootApplicationContext() {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext applicationContext =
      new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    applicationContext.register(WebAppConfig.class);
    return applicationContext;
  }

}
```

Other options can be found here: http://www.kubrynski.com/2014/01/understanding-spring-web-initialization.html